# WebView Direct Download returns HTML which use the original file extension

Tags: android, webview, broadcastreceiver, download

I am trying to perform a direct download inside the `WebView`, not linking to the browser.

```
webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        MimeTypeMap mtm = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);

        // get file name. if filename exists in contentDisposition, use it. otherwise, use the last part of the url.
        String fileName = downloadUri.getLastPathSegment();
        int pos = 0;

        if ((pos = contentDisposition.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf("filename=")) >= 0) {
            fileName = contentDisposition.substring(pos + 9);
            pos = fileName.lastIndexOf(";");

            if (pos > 0) {
                fileName = fileName.substring(0, pos - 1);
            }
        }

        // predict MIME Type
        String fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, fileName.length()).toLowerCase();
        String mimeType = mtm.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);

        // request saving in Download directory
        Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
        request.setTitle(fileName);
        request.setDescription(url);
        request.setMimeType(mimeType);  
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);

        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).mkdirs();

        // request in download manager
        downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    }
});
```

And to open it,

```
// download complete toast
private BroadcastReceiver completeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Resources res = context.getResources();

        // make toast
        Toast.makeText(context, res.getString(R.string.download_complete), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // go to download finished window
        startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // if app stops, stop reciever
        unregisterReceiver(completeReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // app start, start reciever
        IntentFilter completeFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
        registerReceiver(completeReceiver, completeFilter);
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

However, the result is not the original file, but the `HTML` format of the source using the original file extension; e.g. it uses .pdf, but is a HTML file.

What is causing this problem, and How can I fix it?

**Files I get**

First of all, it is impossible to open with a normal PDF viewer, and when I don't open it as PDF, I get a normal HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
…
</html>
```

There is NOTHING SPECIAL in the HTML document.

Comment: Give us some sample of the HTML you get, it's most likely something related to the header. What kind of back end returns the file you request, is there a url?

Answer (score 1):

I found that your **filename** is coming with **quote** so just replace it.

```
fileName=fileName.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

you will get the proper file. I have also used that code in mine and it's successfully worked.

Comment: @jyoon Please add it above "// request saving in Download directory".

Comment: @jyoon Is the downloading of files encrypted in android?

Comment: `fileName=fileName.replaceAll("\", "");`

Comment: @jyoon fileName=fileName.replaceAll("\"", ""); this worked for me